# How to disable any and all eye-candy features on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: snow-leopard, performance, virtualization, ui

I'm going to install [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) virtual machine and work primarily through there.

I want to shut off any and all eye candy on Mac to squeeze out every last bit of performance I can. Akin to "Set for best performance" setting on Windows 7.

> Turn off visual effects
>
> If Windows is running slowly, you can speed it up by disabling some of
>   its visual effects. It comes down to appearance versus performance.
>   Would you rather have Windows run faster or look prettier? If your PC
>   is fast enough, you don't have to make this tradeoff, but if your
>   computer is just barely powerful enough for Windows 7, it can be
>   useful to scale back on the visual bells and whistles.
>
> You can choose which visual effects to turn off, one by one, or you
>   can let Windows choose for you. There are 20 visual effects you can
>   control, such as the transparent glass look, the way menus open or
>   close, and whether shadows are displayed.
>
> To adjust all visual effects for best performance:
>
> Open Performance Information and Tools by clicking the Start button ,
>   and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type Performance
>   Information and Tools, and then, in the list of results, click
>   Performance Information and Tools.
>
> Click Adjust visual effects.   If you're prompted for an administrator
>   password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Click the Visual Effects tab, click Adjust for best performance, and
>   then click OK. (For a less drastic option, select Let Windows choose
>   what’s best for my computer.)

How can I do something similar on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Comment: If you want to work primarily through Mint, you might as well run Mint directly.

Comment: Agreed, this is silly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use applications such as Onyx or Tinkertool to minimize the amount of effects that are displayed on OS X. OS X does not have a built in function to disable graphics like Windows does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some apps, some free and some paid, that can be used to disable or change the behavior of various features. All of these products provide a graphical user interface that (in most cases) works by issuing a Terminal command called `defaults write` to create custom preference files that enable or disable or provide parameters for features that are inaccessible via the Mac OS X user interface.

- [MacPilot](http://www.koingosw.com/products/macpilot.php)
- [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)
- [Lion Tweaks](http://tweaksapp.com)
- [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/)
- [Onyx](http://www.onyxmac.com)

If you want to use the Terminal to create your own defaults write preferences, there have been a lot of posts about that here on Ask Different. The advantage of several of these utilities is that they provide you a list of what tweaks are possible, and also give you a convenient way of reversing the changes if you don't like the results.